# How do I close a Bootstrap/Lightbox modal by clicking anywhere within the viewport?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, lightbox

When the Lightbox image appears, I can only close the modal by clicking outside of it. I would like to close the modal by clicking anywhere within the viewport, as well as with Esc or Space Bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question properly.
The way I read is that you also want to close the modal/ lightbox when clicking inside it. This would be accomplished like this:

```
$('#yourModalID').on('click', function(){
    $(this).modal('close');
});
```

You also want to close the modal on a spacebar press. You could do this like that:

```
$('body').on('keyup', function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 32){ //check if the key pressed was the space bar
         $('#yourModalID').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

You should probably only add this event listener when opening the modal and remove it when the modal is closed to get better performance.